# How to include ember-bootstrap in my project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

This is the github link https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap

I don't think there is a Gem available for this ...

Answer (score 3):

Download the latest version from https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap/downloads

Add it to Assets & load it after Ember